# OS X ejabberd configure error: SQLite3 library >= 3.6.19 was not found

Tags: ejabberd

I tried to install ejabberd in my local Mac OS X machine, but while configuring sqlite using following command as mentioned in steps. I'm stuck at the following issue.

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/my-ejabberd --enable-sqlite
```

Error received

```
checking for SQLite3 library >= 3.6.19... yes
cat: /include/sqlite3.h: No such file or directory
./configure: line 4172: test: !=: unary operator expected
configure: WARNING: Cannot find SQLITE_VERSION macro in sqlite3.h header to retrieve SQLite version!
configure: error: SQLite3 library >= 3.6.19 was not found
```

Steps I followed from - https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/install-osx/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to install vanilla Ejabberd then you can simply do `brew install ejabberd`.

According to the issue, you can also try:

`./configure --prefix=$HOME/my-ejabberd --enable-sqlite --with-sqlite3=/usr/local/opt/sqlite`

P.S. I have filed the issue [on Github Ejabberd](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/3338).

Comment: thanks for support. Later I tried the prosody XMPP server and it worked for me. I just wanted localhost, I'm iOS developer, I just wanted to create a demo by keeping stuff locally and understand how it goes.

Comment: Very cool! A contributor on the issue has provided another configuration command which which future readers can try as well. Happy to hear that it worked out for you.

Comment: Let me try that out.